# The textfield displayed a value which is the calculate result from an action, how to bind the value to core data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm working on mac app project. I have a table and a textfield, one column named price, and the textfield names price as well.  I binding the column price to a controller with keypath arrangedObject, for the textfield, I bind to the same controller, with keypath selection. It worked. It can read the data from user input to textfield.

However now, I need to calculate the number then display the number to the textfield, and then bind the value. so that the column can also display the value. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are already successfully doing the bind part.  So what you need to do is set a calculated value in the text field - which, due to the binding, will then also be shown in the appropriate cell in the table.

To set a value in a text field, you create a new outlet (yourTextFieldName) in the controller class by control-click dragging to a blank line in the controller class .h file - but I'm guessing you are far enough along to know that.  Then to set the value use

[yourTextFieldName aString];

Presuming that your data is numeric (as you refer to computation) you may have to convert it to a string first, possibly with

[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", numericValue ]; // with NSNumber *numericValue or %g if it is a float, or...